# EPP port watchdog timer: how does it work?

Tags: c, timer, watchdog, parallel-port

I am working on a project that involves fast data acquisition (a scientific experiment). I will build an MCU-based module that will supply (at its fastest rate) 2 to 4 bytes of data every 10 microsecond. This data will have to be transferred to a PC in real time for further processing. In order to keep the cost of equipment low I have chosen to use the Enhanced Parallel Port (EPP) of the PC for connection. Its data rate (500 KB/s to 2 MB/s) should be sufficient.

The control program will be programmed in C and will run under DOS (I use DJGPP) and the EPP port will be handled by direct I/O port reading/writing for maximum efficiency.

Unfortunately, most of the documents I found on the net about programming the EPP port are badly written and confusing. My first request is actually for a pointer/link to a comprehensive document that would clearly and logically explain the operation of the EPP port.

Anyway, I managed to find out most of the things I needed, but there is one thing that baffles me. The documents mention a 'watchdog timer' in the EPP port that will set bit 0 of the status register if there is no response from the attached device in about 10 usec. One of the docs even suggests to monitor and reset this status bit if it goes active. AFAIK it is nonsense: the status port is read-only. So how does this watchdog timer really work? I assume that the logical way would be for the LPT controller circuit to reset this bit every time a new read or write operation is initiated. Is this assumption correct? If not, how should I handle this signal?

Comment: can't answer on the watchdog timer thing, but here is some honest advice: stay away from the parallel port, and from DOS. Both are ancient. And scientific to me means 100% correct 100% of the time with no exceptions. So first of all, are you *sure* DOS is 'realtime' enough to acquire data every 10uSec without *ever* missing a frame? And if you're pretty sure, did you already come up with a mechanism to verify this? Second, it's getting harder to find pc's with a parallel port. Third, parallel port is a mess. I've seen it failing to initialize sometimes, requiring frequent restarts. ..

Comment: .. also the mode has to be correct or things don't work. We've had machines resetting LPT mode after power loss etc meaning endless debugging just to come to the conclusion the mode changed to ECP again. Anyway, think about it twice. For about 500$ you can get an actual, professional industry-level PCI/PCIx DAQ card which to me seems much better suited for anything scientific (ok I don't know your actual application of course, but still..).